# Prompt Dialog Does not Show Up after Sending a Attachment To User

Tags: c#, botframework

I am trying to send user a welcome reply on bot connect so I have created a IntroDialog and i am trying to create.

[image: this]

With the below code

```
  [Serializable]
public class IntroDialog : IDialog<object>
{
 public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {           
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
    }

    public virtual async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, 
     IAwaitable<IActivity> argument)
    {
        var activity = await argument;
        var replyMessage = context.MakeMessage();
        //Activity replyToConversation = message.CreateReply("Hello");
        replyMessage.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();

        var imagePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/images/demov1.gif");

        var imageData = Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(imagePath));
        var aa = new Attachment
        {
            Name = "demov1.gif",
            ContentType = "image/gif",
            ContentUrl = $"data:image/gif;base64,{imageData}"
        };
        replyMessage.Attachments.Add(aa);
        await context.PostAsync(replyMessage).ConfigureAwait(false);

        var flowChoices = (IEnumerable<UseSaveInfoResponse>)Enum.GetValues(typeof(UseSaveInfoResponse));
                PromptDialog.Choice(context, null, flowChoices,
                "Out of curiosity, can we ask you something?");


    }

    public async Task FlowChoiceResult(IDialogContext context, 
      IAwaitable<UseSaveInfoResponse> argument)
    {
        await context.PostAsync($"You selected {await argument}");
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
    }
```

}

I am not able to get both the things either only attachment is posted or else on choice is post.

Please help with the solution if possible. Thanks

output i am getting [image: this]

Comment: So you're saying that when you run your intro dialog sometimes it posts the image attachment and sometimes it posts the prompt but it never posts both? In what situations does it post the image attachment and in what situations does it post the prompt?

Comment: no it only post one thing which is first

Comment: `await context.PostAsync(replyMessage).ConfigureAwait(false);`
the below code does not execute after above line 
  `var flowChoices = (IEnumerable<UseSaveInfoResponse>)Enum.GetValues(typeof(UseSaveInfoResponse));
    PromptDialog.Choice(context, null, flowChoices, "Out of curiosity, can we ask you something?");`

Comment: Why did you roll back my edit? You've made your code harder to read

Comment: I just tested your code and it works fine. You'll need to provide more information. Is your IntroDialog meant to respond to a `conversationUpdate`? Why is `FlowChoiceResult` unused? When you say the code doesn't execute, do you mean it just doesn't continue on to `FlowChoiceResult`? Are there any exceptions? Have you tried stepping through your code?

Comment: @KyleDelaney i have no idea when i rolled back your edit, and yes i am calling   await Conversation.SendAsync(message, () => new IntroDialog()); in my conversation update

Comment: @KyleDelaney have made few changes in code check please

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

There are [known issues](https://blog.botframework.com/2018/07/12/how-to-properly-send-a-greeting-message-and-common-issues-from-customers/) with trying to start dialogs while responding to `conversationUpdate` events:

> When ConversationUpdate is **initially** sent, there isn’t enough information in the message to construct the dialog stack.

The recommended solution is to not try to start a dialog until the user has sent a message. If you must start a dialog in response to `conversationUpdate`, you'll need a workaround. Try reading the post I linked for more information.